# Event Duration Calculation and Column Difference using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe imported from CSV File

[image]

Gen_Voltage is actually the Event, When an Event is greater than 2, I have to consider it true. and find the Time duration and Fuel Consumption. I want the result in the following format

[image]

I wrote the following code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col_list = ["SysDT", "Gen_Voltage","Fuel_Ltrs"]
df = pd.read_csv("march_MT1080.csv", usecols=col_list)

#Convert Data Type of Date Column 
df['SysDT'] = df['SysDT'].astype('datetime64[ns]')


dfout = pd.DataFrame()
dfout['Event'] = df['Gen_Voltage']
dfout['EventStartTime'] = df['SysDT']
dfout['change'] = df['Gen_Voltage'].diff()
dfout = dfout.loc[dfout['change'] !=0 ,:]
dfout['EventEndTime'] = dfout['EventStartTime'].shift(-1)
dfout.head(20)
```

This code helps me to display columns Event Start Time (Time 1) & Event Stop Time (Time 2) but now, I am facing a problem to calculate Fuel_Ltrs column.

Comment: It is recommended to add your data as text, we can not copy the contents from image.
You can do `df[:5].to_dict()` and add it back to the question